# Create new 3D matrix from current 3 2D matrices

Tags: matlab

I have 3 2D matrices, each of them represents values in a certain dimension (x,y and z) and each of size 640x480. I want to put them all in a new matrix of size 307200x3 where the matrix will have 307200 rows and each rows carries the x,y and z values
e.g

```
x y z
1 3 4
2 1 3
3 1 1
.
.
.
307200 rows
```

and so on. Can anyone advise me how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
A = [x(:) y(:) z(:)];
```

Comment: If I want to change A back into X,Y and Z matrices?

Comment: `X = reshape(A(:,1), [640, 480])`

Comment: @Dan thanks Dan, and what if I want to make X=640x480x3 to carry all the dimensions?

Comment: @user1460166 That doesn't make sense. You could make `A` 640x480x3, in which case just use Farrukh Naveed's answer. But you only have enough `X` data to make `X` 640 x 480 x **1**.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
final_img(:,:,1)= img1;
final_img(:,:,2)= img2;
final_img(:,:,3)= img3;
```

**final_img** is now a 3D image whereas **img1, img2, img3** are 2D images.

Comment: this is giving a 307200x1x3 not 307200x3

Comment: okay try this:
If **img1, img2, img3** are in grayscale, then: 

    `z = LUT(img1,1);` 
    `z = reshape(z,size(img1));`
    `final_img(:,:,1) = z;`

    `z = LUT(img2,2);` 
    `z = reshape(z,size(img2));`
    `final_img(:,:,2) = z;`

    `z = LUT(img3,3);` 
    `z = reshape(z,size(img3));`
    `final_img(:,:,3) = z;`

Thats it!